Does anyone know how to resolve pandas '__version__' attribute error?
I'm having trouble using pandas
I get this error:
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pandas' has no attribute '__version__' (most likely due to a circular import).
What can it be? The library is installed, but I can't use it.
This is the start of my code:
import pandas as pd

And the error:
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-84d5e4747099> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import pandas as pd

1 frames
/content/spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/pandas/utils.py in require_minimum_pandas_version()
     35             "Pandas >= %s must be installed; however, " "it was not found." % minimum_pandas_version
     36         ) from raised_error
---> 37     if LooseVersion(pandas.__version__) < LooseVersion(minimum_pandas_version):
     38         raise ImportError(
     39             "Pandas >= %s must be installed; however, "

AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pandas' has no attribute '__version__' (most likely due to a circular import)

screenshot

This does not seem like an error directly related to pandas. On the other hand, if it is, your pandas installation may be corrupt or there is a bug in the published package.

Please post the full error message and code (i.e. import pandas as pd) as text. We prefer to avoid screenshots of text, but this is fine since it adds context. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and see [ask] if you want more tips.

Yes. It's quite difficult. You might have to restart everything

Possible duplicate: Importing a library from (or near) a script with the same name raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or an ImportError or NameError. This would apply if you wrote your own script called pandas.py.

You need to include the "1 frames". I think you can click to expand it, but I haven't used Colab myself.

Got it, but the file name is apache_spark_pandas.py

Have you tried to uninstall and re-install? If so give the env variables in the virtual env you are using.

Its because you are importing pandas as pd and using pandas to check version which cannot be done.
Replace:
pandas.__version__

With:
pd.__version__


That would result in some other name resolution error. Look at the traceback and you'll see that __version__ is used in the pandas library - not something OP would edit.
